# Jack and PulseEffects issue

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3 (two PCs) and 19.04 (one PC).

In all those machines I have an "issue", but I don't know if it is something wrong or "by-default".

The issue is when I use Jack Audio Service and PulseEffects. Everything works so fine, and the soud is great! But...

PulseEffects doesn't appear into the "Connections" panel of "qjackctl".

Even the fact that PulseEffects is working with Jack... Why it doesn't appear in that panel?

Is there something wrong? Or... Is it a "by-default" condition?

Comment: pulse-effects is running in Pulseaudio not JACK. there are other packages that can host the same DSP effects in JACK (jack-rack, or carla), and many other different DSP effects in other packages too

Comment: Thanks a lot for your data, nik gnomic!!!